# Как изменить футер Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, css

Есть футер-шаблон с [сайта](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/).
Нужно изменить ширину, скажем не 100% а 90%, как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
margin: 0 auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 90%; // заменить со 100%
```